# Busy time is too high for simple process function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Finally, after a month of research I found the main reason.

The main reason was IP2Location. I am using IP2Location java library to search ip address location in the BIN files. In the peak time, it causes a problem. At least i can avoid to problem by passing `IP2Proxy.IOModes.IP2PROXY_MEMORY_MAPPED` parameter before reading the bin files.

And also I just found that a few state object doesn't match with POJO standard which causes high load.

---

I am using flink v1.13, there are 4 task managers (per 16 cpu) with 3800 tasks (default application parallelism is 28)

In my application one operator has always high busy time (around %80 - %90).

If I restart the flink application, then busy time decreases, but after 5-10 hours running busy time increases again.

In the grafana, I can see that busy time for ProcessStream increases. Here is the PromethuesQuery: **avg((avg_over_time(flink_taskmanager_job_task_busyTimeMsPerSecond[1m]))) by (task_name)**

There is no backpressure in the ProcessStream task. To calculate backPressure time, I am using: **flink_taskmanager_job_task_backPressuredTimeMsPerSecond**

But I couldn't find any reason for that.

Here is the code :

```java
private void processOne(DataStream<KafkaObject> kafkaLog) {
    kafkaLog
         .filter(new FilterRequest())
         .name(FilterRequest.class.getSimpleName())
         .map(new MapToUserIdAndTimeStampMs())
         .name(MapToUserIdAndTimeStampMs.class.getSimpleName())
         .keyBy(UserObject::getUserId) // returns of type int
         .process(new ProcessStream())
         .name(ProcessStream.class.getSimpleName())
         .addSink(...)
         
        ;
}

// ...
// ...

public class ProcessStream extends KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, UserObject, Output>
{
    private static final long STATE_TIMER = // 5 min in milliseconds;

    private static final int AVERAGE_REQUEST = 74;
    private static final int STANDARD_DEVIATION = 32;
    private static final int MINIMUM_REQUEST = 50;
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 70;


    private transient ValueState<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> state;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception
    {
        ValueStateDescriptor<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>(
                ProcessStream.class.getSimpleName(),
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {}));

        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(stateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(UserObject value, KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, UserObject, Output>.Context ctx, Collector<Output> out) throws Exception
    {
        Tuple2<Integer, Integer> stateValue = state.value();

        if (Objects.isNull(stateValue)) {
            stateValue = Tuple2.of(1, 0);
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(value.getTimestampMs() + STATE_TIMER);
        }

        int totalRequest = stateValue.f0;
        int currentScore = stateValue.f1;

        if (totalRequest >= MINIMUM_REQUEST && currentScore >= THRESHOLD)
        {
            out.collect({convert_to_output});
            state.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            stateValue.f0 = totalRequest + 1;
            stateValue.f1 =  calculateNextScore(stateValue.f0);
            state.update(stateValue);
        }
    }

    private int calculateNextScore(int totalRequest)
    {
        return (totalRequest - AVERAGE_REQUEST ) / STANDARD_DEVIATION;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, UserObject, Output>.OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Output> out) throws Exception
    {
        state.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using event time or processing time for the workflow? If it's event time (based on UserObject. getTimestampMs()) then you want to register a timer using `. registerEventTimeTimer()`, not `. registerProcessingTimeTimer()`.

Comment: @kkrugler, I am using processing time

Comment: One situation where I've seen CPU increase over time is when state fills up TM memory, and you start getting a lot of GC activity as you approach a full heap.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a timestamp value from your incoming record (`value.getTimestampMs() + STATE_TIMER`), you want to be running with event time, and setting watermarks based on that incoming record's timestamp. Otherwise you have no idea when the timer is actually firing, as the record's timestamp might be something completely different than your current processor time.

This means you also want to use `.registerEventTimeTimer()`.

Without these changes you might be filling up TM heap with uncleared state, which can lead to high CPU load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, most probably TM filling up with uncleared state, how can verify that (especially with promethues query)

Comment: I use the Flink UI - it provides a view of each TM's memory usage.